# C++ no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm having a problem with the intellisense of visual studio, it marks me that i can't push to a vector of a struct i made to store certain data for a little OpenGL project, i try to pass the data of the new struct i want to add to the vector but it makes an error, but i don't know why, when i create the struct and store in a variable and then push the variable to the vector, it doesn't mark an error, so i don't know whats the problem, when i passing a variable which is an int, it marks me the error, but when i pass a raw number, directly in the constructor of the struct is fine.

```
struct VertexBufferElement
{
    unsigned int type;
    unsigned int count;
    bool normalize;
};


void funtion(int count)
{
    //the vector of the struct above
    std::vector<VertexBufferElement> elements;

    //This is not allowed
    elements.push_back({GL_FLOAT,count,false });
        
    //This is allowed
    elements.push_back({GL_FLOAT,4,false});
        
    //This is allowed
    struct VertexBufferElement vb = { GL_FLOAT,count,false };
    elements.push_back(vb);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the exact error you get.

Comment: You should take IntelliSense errors with a handful of salt. "Live" checking of C++ is pretty much an unsolved problem.

Comment: The title of the post is the error it marks me

Comment: It's not the full text of the error message though

Comment: @user7860670 i'm sorry, that was a sintax error when i was typing the code, but yeah, it works without the typing error, but the issue is when i pass the count variable to be store it the count att of the struct

Comment: function argument `count` is of `int` type therefore implicit conversion to `count` field of `unsigned int` type may lead to data loss. So you should either use the same type for `count` everywhere or use explicit conversion. `elements.push_back({GL_FLOAT, static_cast< unsigned int >(count),false });`

Answer (score 5):

As you said:

> // This is allowed

> struct VertexBufferElement vb = { GL_FLOAT,count,false };

So you should be able to use:

```cpp
elements.emplace_back(GL_FLOAT,count,false);
```

without triggering a faulty intellisense error on overload resolution.

It also constructs the element in place (as in the "allowed" example you posted) so it's more tidy - I'll avoid saying better performing here bc the difference should be minuscule

Comment: It only initializes in-place since C++20. Granted, it's the middle of 2023, but in case folks can't get it working: this is why.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `count` is of type `int`, so converting it to `unsigned int VertexBuffer::count` is a narrowing conversion, which isn't allowed in a braced initializer.

It is allowed for constant expressions like `4` because that can be converted to `unsigned int` without narrowing (it will definitely be in range, i.e. is not negative).

You need to either make the argument `unsinged int`:

```cpp
void function(unsigned count) { ... }
```

Add a cast:

```cpp
void function(int count) {
    elements.push_back({GL_FLOAT, unsigned(count), false });
    struct VertexBufferElement vb = { GL_FLOAT, unsigned(count), false };
}
```

Or use a parenthesised initialiser (in C++20/23 mode):

```cpp
void function(int count) {
    elements.push_back(VertexBufferElement(GL_FLOAT, count, false));
    struct VertexBufferElement vb(GL_FLOAT, count, false);
}
```

(By the way `struct VertexBufferElement vb = { GL_FLOAT,count,false };` is also "not allowed" because of the narrowing, but many compilers do allow it with only a warning as an extension)